# Printing objects of one value based on another value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, console.log

I want to `console.log` a value within an array of objects based on another specific value. For example, I have a simple array  of objects. For all of the objects with v: 1, I want to print the z value.

```
  var array = [
    {v:1, z: 4},
    {v:3, z: 8},
    {v:4, z: 6},
    {v:1, z: 4},
    {v:2, z: 9},
    {v:2, z: 3},
    {v:4, z: 7},
    {v:1, z: 5},
  ];
```

I tried something like `for (array.v(1) => { console.log(array.z); });` but the syntax isnt correct. What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: `array.filter(o => o.v === 1).forEach(o => console.log(o.z));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
array.forEach( function(a) { if ( a.v == 1 ) console.log(a.z); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a if statement to your for each loop

Also you can use a filter function but this will print the object that meet your filter, not only the z value

```js
var array = [
    {v:1, z: 4},
    {v:3, z: 8},
    {v:4, z: 6},
    {v:1, z: 4},
    {v:2, z: 9},
    {v:2, z: 3},
    {v:4, z: 7},
    {v:1, z: 5},
  ];
  
 console.log('For Each')
 array.forEach(o=>{ if(o.v == 1)console.log(o.z)})
 console.log('Filter')
 console.log(JSON.stringify(array.filter(o=>o.v==1)))
```

Comment: Both of these solutions work perfectly. I went went the first because of simplicity. No need to stringify in this case.